# RewriteRule that preserves GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, get

What is wrong with this rewrite rule?

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.+)$ api/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I simply want "index.php?url=" to be added after api/ and before the rest of the get parameters.

```
api/image/upload&arg1=1&text=lorem+ipsum
```

to

```
api/index.php?url=image/upload&arg1=1&text=lorem+ipsum
```

What is wrong with (.+) to get everything after api/?

Comment: ^api/([a-zA-Z0-9/_\&\=\%]+)$ works but will not work with different language specific characters as åäöøæé and so on... That is why I would like ^api/(.+)$ to work instead. . should mean any character except line break or end of string so I don't get it why it does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [keep url parameters with htaccess rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/keep-url-parameters-with-htaccess-rewrite)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The regex on the RewriteRule is only run against the path part of the URL, not the query parameters. Fortunately there is the [`[QSA]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to preserve existing query parameters.

Comment: Wonderful! This solved my problems! I have allso found a JS function to url encode all non a-zA-Z0-9_. characters http://cass-hacks.com/articles/code/js_url_encode_decode/

Comment: QSA saved me! Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something to stop infinite recursion?

```
 RewriteRule ^api/(.+)$ api/index.php?url=$1 [R=301,L]
```

or some equivalent

Comment: I had [L] before but it does not make any diffrence. My problem is that apache2 reports that the only get parameter is [url] => index.php , all other parameters are gone and url parameter should be 'image/upload'. When I use the rule ^api/([a-zA-Z0-9/_]+)$ instead the url parameter is 'image/upload' but I loose all other GET parameters instead.

Comment: I'm allso not trying to do a redirect, just get the text between api/ and before the first & to get the string prefixed by "index.php?url=" and the rest of the GET parameters preserved

Comment: How does `R=301` work here? It is not in the docs at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Search for "'redirect|R [=code]' (force redirect)" on that page.  It's if you want to specify the exact HTTP response code for the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must write your domain name before the regex stuff. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+).com/api/(.*)$ "$1.com/api/index.php?url=$2" [R=301,L]
```