# .htaccess RewriteRule to preserve GET URL parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

I'm having issues keeping the parameters of the URL working after an `.htaccess` URL rewrite.

My `.htaccess` rewrite is as follows:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2
```

Which means:

`example.com/index.php?lang=en&page=product` displays as `example.com/en/product`

For some reason, when I add a `?model=AB123&color=something` at the end of my URLs I am not able to retrieve those parameters in PHP using `$_GET['model']` and `$_GET['color']` even though they are present in the displayed URL.

Why aren't the variables passed along?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need to append with the [QSA] (query string append) tag. Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. It's funny how simple the solution is after some of the things I tried...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on mine, even with the QSA tag. The correct page displays, but because the $_GET seems unobtainable, it throws loads of errors. I'm using `RewriteRule ^details/([^/])/?$ details?Pin=$1 [QSA]`

Comment: You sir are a legend :)