# Rewrite rule in htaccess to keep parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've written the following rewrite rule which works fine when no parameters (no page numbers, no products per page, no sort order etc)

```
RewriteRule ^(?!bench/).*cat_2.html(\.[a-z]{3,4})?(.*)  "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.co\.uk\/bench\/cat_2\.html\?mode\=allBrands" [R=301,L]
```

This makes sure the URL is optimized on Googles results.  So

- http://www.mysite.co.uk/bench-clothing/cat_2.html?mode=allBrands#

gets changed to

- http://www.mysite.co.uk/bench/cat_2.html?mode=allBrands

`mode=allBrands` will always be set.

So if i click on a link to go to

- http://www.mysite.co.uk/bench-clothing/cat_2.html?mode=allBrands&ppp=64&sort=desc&page=2

it gets redirected to

- http://www.mysite.co.uk/bench/cat_2.html?mode=allBrands

which is the first page.

Any help would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [keep url parameters with htaccess rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/keep-url-parameters-with-htaccess-rewrite)

Answer (score 3):

change `[R=301,L]` to `[R=301,L,QSA]`

More info : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `QSA` flag to your rewrite rule, so that the brackets look like this:

```
[R=301,L,QSA]
```

This tells apache to append any existing query string to the new query string in the target (`mode=allBrands`).

Comment: Hi Thanks for that.  Its adds the parameters but leaves the orignal so   http://www.tdffashion.co.uk/bench/cat_2.html?mode=allBrands  turns into  http://www.tdffashion.co.uk/bench/cat_2.html?mode=allBrands&mode=allBrands.   How can I remove the extra parameters before using the QSA on them?  Thanks

Comment: remove the `?mode=AllBrands` from the RewriteRule's target. The query string will automatically be appended.

Comment: Is that syntax correct? Shouldn't it be ",QSA" (with comma) instead of ".QSA" (dot)?

Comment: @JavierGuerrero you're correct, I had a typo in the answer