# htaccess Rewrite dont pass querystring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have the following rules in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ redirect.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(?!js|css|png)([^.]*)$ redirect.php [L]
```

everything works perfect except for one thing, the querystring.
for some reason the querystring disapper...

I got the following url myweb.com/subscribe?email=blablabla
in redirect.php I have the following line:

```
echo $_GET['email']; //should echo the email
```

and it doesnt echo anything...
***I checked that it does rewrite to redirect.php**

any Idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess RewriteRule to preserve GET URL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/htaccess-rewriterule-to-preserve-get-url-parameters)

Comment: QSA flag didnt work. I tried everything...

Comment: Note you have 2 rules, use `QSA`, which _is_ the correct answer, in both.

Comment: @Wrikken ofc, I did it in both and it didnt work.. I am not that idiot just a little bit

Comment: Let's be clear, `QSA` (or Leonard's answer for that matter) works, so something else must be going on. More redirects somewhere maybe? You could make the redirects temporarily external (`[R]`) to check in the network log of your browser what & how things are happening.

Comment: Using [R] cause the web to redirect to redirect.php?email=blablabla as it should and it echo the email. Why without the R flag it doesnt work?

Comment: Ok I investigated it a little more and the problem seem to be with  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(?!js|css|png)([^.]*)$ redirect.php [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by the following steps:

1. I didnt want to rewrite css, js, png etc.. files so in my last rule it was included in the regex - I splitted it.
2. Added [QSA] flag to 2 last rules
3. Added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
4. Changed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.

this is how it looks:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule \.(ico|css|png|js|txt|xml)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ redirect.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php [QSA,L]
```