# htaccess non-rewritten parameters aren't working with rewritten parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have following htaccess rules in the folder example.com/folder/index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-filter-(.*)\.html$ $1.php?filter=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

So the URL is rewritten to: example.com/folder/index.html and example.com/folder/index-filter-stuff.html

Now when I echo $_GET["bla"] from example.com/folder/index.html?bla=value it works, I get the value. But when I echo it from example.com/folder/index-filter-stuff.html?bla=value then it's not working. So I get only values from non rewritten parameters when the URL doesn't contain rewritten parameters, what could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess RewriteRule to preserve GET URL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/htaccess-rewriterule-to-preserve-get-url-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are missing the `QSA` flag: "query string append":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-filter-(.*)\.html$ $1.php?filter=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [QSA]
```

I suggest you take a look at the excellent documentation of apaches [rewriting module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It explains such things in detail and has lots of really good examples.