# .htacess pretty url which also allow normal get parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following .htacess code which allow three $_GET parameters to show in pretty manner

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%]+)/(.*)$ search.php?name=$1&city=$2&age=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%]+)/(.*)$ search.php?name=$1&city=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%]+)/(.*)$ search.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The url will look like domain.com/search/name/city/age

but I want to add more dynamic filters like  domain.com/search/name/city/age?gender=male

now my .htaccess don't treat `?gender=male` as normal get parameters. If I print all $_GET values in php using `print_r($_GET)`, it will show me only $_GET values that I have written in .htaccess

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to match `?gender=male`.
Also, you can replace your patterns by `([^/]+)` (every characters except a slash `/`) to be more generic.

Here's an example of capturing `gender` with `/search/name/city/age?gender=something`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gender=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?name=$1&city=$2&age=$3&gender=%1 [L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?name=$1&city=$2&age=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?name=$1&city=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?name=$1 [L]
```

---

EDIT: easier version with `QSA` flag (query string append)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?name=$1&city=$2&age=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?name=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I will accept this answer. Thank you. Just one little problem. Url ending with `/` won't work. Any modifications?

Comment: I edited my answer to work with both (with or without trailing slash). The choice is up to you (but choose one, otherwise you'll have some duplicate content problem)

Comment: Working fine. Thank you. And I will appreciate if you explain me how duplication problem can occur? Just to make sure it won't happen.

Comment: Well duplicate content is when you have 2 different urls leading to same content. In your case, i made trailing slash `/` optional (`/?`), so `/search/name/city/age` and `/search/name/city/age/` lead to same content but one is considered as a page and the other as a folder by search engines

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

will it prevent that

Comment: No, those conditions are for checking if it's an existing folder or file. A good practice is to decide if you want your links to be with or without trailing slash and then keep it all along. And in my code, you can replace `/?` by nothing if you don't want a trailing slash after your link (or by `/` if you want it)

Comment: Oh. Just one last question. If I have like 10 dynamic $_GET parameters to add, do I need to add all those in .htaccess code or is there any wildcard for that?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/htaccess-rewriterule-to-preserve-get-url-parameters solution saves all these efforts

Comment: Yes in your case it's easier to use `QSA` flag. You can see my edited answer about it