# Editing the urls on a specific website

Tags: javascript, html

I was just wondering if anyone could enlighten me with some knowledge.
What I want to do is to "overlap" an url. For example:

> website.com/index.php?page=something&id=**5432**

becomes (taking the id from the first url):

> website.com/src/popup.php?page=something&id=**5432**

Any quick and simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this, like, a browser plugin you want to make? Or are you developing this site? Kinda hard to tell what you're working with. In terms of string manipulation, this seems pretty doable; regexes might be the most straightforward way depending on how familiar you are with them.

Comment: Sorry for being a little vague. It is indeed a browser plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you you're looking for some kind of redirection here.

I'm not sure if you're thinking of using entirely javascript here, as you've shown a PHP file extension.

**Javascript**

For a Javascript-only solution, you might try something like this:

```
//Parameter function thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/917035
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

//Build the new location string.
var page = getParameterByName("page");
var id = getParameterByName("id");
var locationString = 'http://website.com/src/popup.page?page=' + page + '&id=' + id;
//Redirect
window.location = locationString;
```

Alternatively you could achieve the same thing with PHP:

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $page = $_GET['something'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $locationString = 'website.com/src/popup.page?page=' . $page . '&id=' . $id;
    header('Location: ' . $locationString);
?>
```

Which would take the parameters in your URL query (`page` and `id`) and then pass them into the `header` request to redirect the user away.

If you're looking for a long-term solution for *all* pages, there are options available in the ways of editing your `.htaccess` files, similar to how [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4071190/917035) uses a `RewriteRule` to preserve the parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I failed to mention that I do not own the website I intend to make change to.

Comment: @JohnDough That's okay! The javascript code there should still work though, I would imagine? Most browser plugins have access to all of the javascript features and window control too.