# .htaccess rewrite for multiple variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so I have a few different links on my website, and I am looking for some advice on how I can achieve this.

Some example links:

```
domain/index.php?page=commandCenter&ID=40
domain/index.php?page=view&action=edit&ID=40
domain/index.php?page=acpDashboard
```

I would like the rewrite to look like the following for each link:

```
domain/commandCenter/40
domain/view/edit/40
domain/acpDashboard
```

Though it seems in order for this to work, I need to have something in place for those variables.

The last link would not work, but

```
domain/acpDashboard/0/0
```

is what it needs to work.

Is this possible, and how would I go about it?  I only have 3 different variables page, action, and ID.

Here is my htaccess atm!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?    page=$1&action=$2&ID=$3 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Your here is wrong you can reference [.htaccess RewriteRule to preserve GET URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/htaccess-rewriterule-to-preserve-get-url-parameters) this answer

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&ID=$3 [L]
```