# Custom url for $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm developing a website and I want to make like a profile page.

I was wondering if I could change from `profile?name=BlaBla` to `profile/BlaBla`.

How can I do this?

Comment: which server are you using?  You can do this with htaccess on apache server

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about because I'm a beginner.. I want to try it on localhost with xampp

Comment: htaccess [rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/715105) might help you here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess RewriteRule to preserve GET URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/htaccess-rewriterule-to-preserve-get-url-parameters)

Comment: I've tried to do this with htaccess rewrite but it's removing the design...

Comment: Are you already removing the .php extension on your server? `profile?name=BlaBla`. And how is this related to javascript/jquery?

Comment: If you're styling is not working you have an issue with the way you are referencing the style files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ ./profile?name=$1    [L]
```

Comment: I've tried to do this but I've got a problem...https://imgur.com/a/0r5xFhP

Comment: What problem @CTMBeast ?

Comment: In my last comment i've attached a link... On my website the design it's not showing up

Comment: Please check page source about what CSS URL is ?

Comment: Just for testing Can you try with `localhost/g4l/profile/name/CTMBeast`

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment above.
It seems that the CSS and other resources path are getting messed up when you are rewriting urls.

Please try and fix the css path by providing absolute urls. You could also use the  HTML tag to set the base url to use relative paths for resources.

Answer (score 0):

For This Process Better to use MVC Framework. Because in MVC already set Routing then from Route it's good to secure your data as well as fomating will be  `http://your-URL/controller/ID`. I suggest you should use Codeigniter or Laravel Framework for this project. Or If you are generating API then use CodeIgniter, Laravel or Slim Framework for Routing.