# apache redirect based on a form values

Tags: apache

I have an old web application that is fronted with Apache/2.2.34.  I plan on using RewriteEngine and RewriteRule to redirect some requests without updating the application.  However, one of the rules I need is dependent based off of form values.  For example, I want to redirect "/navigation" to "some place else" only when the form element "form_action" is equal to 5.  Is there a way to do this in Apache?

Comment: You would need to write a web application in your favorite language to handle those form posts and issue an appropriate redirect. Apache itself does not inspect the body of `POST` requests.

Comment: Can you maybe use `method = 'get'` to give Apache access to the form data?

Comment: Is your `<form>` `method` attribute `GET` or `POST`? If not specified it is `GET`.

Comment: for action usually will be an url. Not a number

Comment: @Jay kindly look at this regarding formaction https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formaction.asp

Comment: is 5 and 5+ indicates your undefined nav options?

Comment: Sorry for missing these responses earlier,  This form does a post: <form name="navigation" method="post" action="navigation">.  There is also a hidden field in the form named "form_action".  The navigation servlet determines where to direct the request based on the form value.
However,  I was hoping to have apache catch these requests, and direct the browser to some other place based on the logic I shared above.  I wanted to pursue an apache redirect solution to avoid altering a very old application.

Comment: What does "is 5 and 5+ indicates your undefined nav options? " mean?

Comment: like 1-4 indicates your Nav options

Comment: I've made changes to my application so I no longer need an apache solution,  However, if there is an answer to my question, it may be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Form action values are  urls may be absolute urls or relative.
Not Sure of the Exact reWrite rule but wrote based on other rewrite examples

for internal reDirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    "^/5"  "/navigation" [PT]
```

for External reDirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    "^/5"  "/navigation" [R]
```

Comment: Question has been update So Answer has to be updated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best thing that could fix your problem is to send the data over `GET request`. The reason for doing this is that you can pass the form's inputs as URL parameters and then create a `RewriteRule` to check the parameters value.

i.e.:

```
<form method="get" action="/nagivation">
  <input type="text" name="form_action" value=""> <!-- Your 'form_action' input -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <!-- Your submit button -->
</form>
```

The above form, will send its data to `https://www.example.com/nagivation?form_action=5` only if the user fills the input with the value of '5' and submits the form. Also, you will see the URL in your browser changing to the one I provided.

so, if your `RewriteRule` catches the `/navigation?form_action=5` you can succesfully do the redirect.

Check this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method) for better understanding

Finally, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/htaccess-rewriterule-to-preserve-get-url-parameters) you can see how to add a RewriteRule using URL parameters.

Comment: The reason for my question was in the hopes of not altering the application, changing from a post to a get would alter the application in my case

Comment: In that case, try to use this as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data