# Use Apache2 RewriteRule to change a dynamic URL segment into a parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I use an apache2 rewriterule to change this URL:

```
http://somewhere.com/sensors/435?pw=12345
```

into this one:

```
http://somewhere.com/sensors?pw=12345&id=435
```

Where '435' changes per request?

I've found a partial answer here:
[RewriteRule that preserves GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321702/rewriterule-that-preserves-get-parameters)
However I'm stuck at this point:

```
RewriteRule ^sensors/(.+)$ sensors?id=$1 [L] [QSA]
```

The param order doesn't matter, I can't work out how to change the existing '?' into '&'.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried by something similar should work:

```
RewriteRule ^sensors/([^?]+)?(.*)$ sensors?$2&id=$1 [L] [QSA]
```

Instead of using only one capturing group we separate in two, allowing us to rebuild the new querystring easily.

Comment: Thanks, I see the logic. I tried your example and the rules being ignored at the moment so I'm playing abit with the regex. Once it works properly I'll post it here.