# Laravel public folder retured 404 (.htaccess)

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file. With this file, I am detecting the language code by subdomain (HTTP_HOST).

There is no problem here, however, when I redirect incoming requests to the files under the public folder, I get a 404 error and also the language becomes inoperable.

```
SetEnv DEFAULT_LANG en

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Set the language parameter by HTTP_HOST
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.([a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]

    # Set the language parameter default
    RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:en]

    # Set the language query string if absent
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]

    # Finally rewrite the request URI to the /public folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please provide your reference implementation for the language handling by subdomain - the documentation of the configuration is missing. And can you add a bit more context? What is your reasoning about what this configuration should do, what does it instead and what do you mean by "redirect"? Normally that means a HTTP redirect in context of a webserver configuration, but there are no redirects configured in your questions configuration code.

Comment: Does this already answer your question: [RewriteRule that preserves GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3321702/367456)?

Comment: I'm sad. does not answer. Because my problem is to redirect both under language parameter and public. Both do not work at the same time.

Comment: Well, QSA is missing with the L flagged rule. See the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the following:

```
SetEnv DEFAULT_LANG en

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.([a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
    RewriteRule .* - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:en]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Using the above the language detection should work even when redirecting to the files under the public folder. The `%{ENV:LANGUAGE}` variable will be preserved throughout the rewriting process, therefore the correct language parameter should be passed to the files in the public folder.

Comment: What do you mean by _" when redirecting to the files"_?

Comment: Why do you suggest in your answer to append the parameter two times? Or perhaps better asked: When you diagnose that as the fix, why do you keep the previous directive you identified as errorneous?

Comment: first default language.other one is the variable language.

Comment: I tried your code. language parameter works. only files still return 404.

Comment: @Hakre Incoming requests in laravel are directed to the public directory. Ex: x.com/public/files

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz: The `public` must never be part of the URL. Perhaps that's not well understood? /E: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19923091/367456 and [Directory Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation#directory-configuration)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed the code you gave. @hakre